# Motorola SDK for android

Tags: android, motorola-droid

I want to use bluetooth 4.0(BLE) technical in android application but the Motorola SDK is required for android development.

I have tried http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/us-en/motodev_lp.html

and http://developer.motorola.com/tools/resources/

two sites but all of the two links go to the home page.

How can i get the SDK? Or the SDK is not available?

Thanks.

Comment: ya I face this problem too, was reading something about AES encryption in Android in motorola dev website, but it has been routed to the consumer homepage. Previously I use google webcache to continue reading it. But recently the google webcache is gone also.